# construct php not work show blank in my browser

Tags: php, oop

i create a php class file but when it run it not work

```
class User {

  public function __construct(){
    $host_name='localhost';
    $username='root';
    $password='';
    $database_name='php';
    $conn=mysql_connect($host_name,$username,$password);
    if(!$conn)
    {
        die('Database Not Connected!');
    }
    else{
        echo 'Database connected';
    }
  }

}
```

but without use class it run

Comment: You have to call your class! Such as `$user = new User();`

Comment: thanks it work and solving my problem

Comment: Also, the old `mysql` library for PHP is about to be deprecated, in favor of the `mysqli` library. Consider switching your codebase to use the new library, if possible.

Comment: Better than `mysqli` is `PDO`

Comment: @MahbubKhan The _taxicala_'s answer properly answers your question, it should be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate the class by using the `new` keyword. Remember to use the parenthesis in order to call the class constructor method:

```
class User {

  public function __construct(){
    $host_name='localhost';
    $username='root';
    $password='';
    $database_name='php';
    $conn=mysql_connect($host_name,$username,$password);
    if(!$conn)
    {
        die('Database Not Connected!');
    }
    else{
        echo 'Database connected';
    }
  }

}

$myUser = new User();
```